# chromedriver crash problem with different project on same machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, bdd

it might look duplicate issue but could not find a proper solution. so raising here for any suggestion.

I have two projects on same machine with different folder, one is BDD framework and other is TestNG framework. I use the same chromedriver (ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138) on both framework under '/resources' folder and using that to launch like below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
browser.manage().window().maximize();
browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

When i run my BDD framework it launches chrome and executes my test. But while running the TestNG framework, it gives below error.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9453625af54f11fd83179e23450fa-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#999}) on port 5661
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '<host>', ip: '<ip>', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00355E93+2449043]
    Ordinal0 [0x00288281+1606273]
    Ordinal0 [0x0017F889+522377]
```

i run my BDD as maven project through `mvn clean install` command and run the TestNG project as normal right click and `run as test class` file.

what am i missing here, any help on this please.

**Updated with chrome versions.......**

Version on BDD project

```
c:\BDD\Test_Project\src\test\resources\Drivers>chromedriver.exe --version                                                             
ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9453625af54f11fd83179e23450fa-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#999})
```

Version in TestNG project

```
c:\Users\user\Downloads\gca_automation\src\test\resources>chromedriver.exe --version                                                          
ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9453625af54f11fd83179e23450fa-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#999})
```

my chrome browser version `Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: any help on this please? what could be the problem here..?

Comment: If you are running on remote machine make sure you are specifying the port, i see here a different port(5661) rather that default 4444

Comment: No, i am not running in any remote machine. Both are in my local laptop, and running in same machine. Only difference is both are in different folder.

Comment: If is related to port, what should i do to make a default port and try?

Comment: Seems is ok, i just did a test and the same happens for me, starts on a different port.

Comment: i updated the version details on the question, please help on this. it blocks my testing. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Set absolute path to the driver, it might be an issue there, see the update from my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217562/discussion-between-mmar-and-lauda).

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a compatibility between `chromedriver` and the installed version of chrome.

Check your chrome version and make sure you have the appropriate chromedriver version, you should see recommendations in the official website from where you are downloading chrome
(now https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

> Tip: you could use `webdrivermanager` from bonigarcia. This is a library that manages the chromedriver automatically for you, it will check chrome version and get the version you need and also set the `webdriver.chrome.driver`

Also do not run as root.

Update: kill all chrome and chromedriver processes, use File.separator when setting path to the driver e.g. like
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: I have checked the version as said, all are same. As said, its running in BDD project but not in TestNG project. Regarding the ```webdrivermanager```, i cannot use that as my enterprise blocks that. so i need to have the physical driver file in my project.

Comment: Check again all the versions for all chromedriver and chrome and restart chrome if is opened, also close all processes with chrome/chromedriver from task manager.

Comment: i tried all the way as you said ```Relative Path```, ```Absolute Path```, using ```user.dir``` , but no luck. all gives the same error.